# Confusion in data type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

What kind of data is it in JavaScript.

```
var data1 = "\234";
var data2 = '\075\162\077\174\275\022\150\314\272\032\201\122';
```

And how can I create them from a string.

Comment: Those are strings. They even work in C so they're not a javascript specific thing. They're octal escapes -  a feature of the string literal syntax. They're common in many programming languages.

Comment: For example `\234` represents the byte 10011100 which is the byte 0x9c in hexadecimal

Answer (score 2):

These are all unicode characters as mentioned by Suren.

For details have a look [here](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html).

You can use `decodeURIComponent` to read the data.

To read more about `decodeURIComponent` read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

```js
var data2 = "\075\162\077\174\275\022\150\314\272\032\201\122";
var str = decodeURIComponent(data2);
console.log(str);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This are `UNICODE` or `ASCII` symbols which are stored in the string, actually each of this symbols are also strings, but in the output you see another result which is differed from that one in the string. If you print them you can see what they actually keep inside.

```js
var data2 = '\075\162\077\174\275\022\150\314\272\032\201\122';

console.log(data2)
```

Comment: You can't split them by \ because that string does not contain the character \

Comment: woah really? i figured they wouldn't be parsed to unicode until they were displayed somewhere. didn't know that